# Error in creating a stack using linked list

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, stack

I am creating a stack using a linked list(I am only in the push part). I have declared my structure as

```
struct LinkedStack {
    int data;
    struct LinkedStack* next;
};
```

I have 3 pointers to LinkedStack declared globally.

```
struct LinkedStack *first = NULL;
struct LinkedStack *previous = NULL;
struct LinkedStack *current = NULL;
```

In the `main()` I'v writen this

```
int data = 0, choice = 0;
if(current == NULL) {
     printf("\nNo Memory Allocated");
}

printf("\n1. Push Data");
printf("\n2. Pop Data");
printf("\n3. Display The Stack");
printf("\n4. Exit");

scanf("%d", &choice);

switch(choice) {
    case 1:
        printf("Enter the data:: ");
        scanf("%d", &data);
        push(&current, data);
        break;
}
```

The push function I have written is this-

```
void push(struct LinkedStruct **s, int usrdata) {
    if(first == NULL) {
        first = *s;
    }  
    if(previous != NULL) {
        previous->next = *s;
    } 

    *s->data = usrdata;
    previous = *s;
    *s->next = NULL;
}
```

But this results into compilation failure. The errors are-

> Request for member 'data' in something which isn't a structure or an
>   union
>   Request for member 'next' in something which isn't a structure or an
>   union

and the line numbers of these errors are these lines:

```
  *s->data = usrdata;
  previous = *s;
  *s->next = NULL;
```

Could you tell me why is this happening?

Comment: Where are you allocating the `LinkedStruct`s?

Comment: void push(struct  LinkedStruct *s,int usrdata). you don't need pointer to pointer here..

Comment: Pick a language. Either C or C++, but not both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "arrow" operator have higher [precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than the dereference operator. So from the compilers point of view you have written e.g.

```
*(s->data)=usrdata;
```

You need to use parentheses:

```
(*s)->data=usrdata;
```

Answer (score -1):

you should use `s->data = usrdata` or `(*s).data = usrdata`.

Comment: This is incorrect, as `s` is defined as `struct LinkedStruct **s` (note pointer to pointer), therefore you want `(*s)->data` not `s->data` or `(*s).data`.